# com.here.schema.geometry.v2.geometry.Geometry to WKT, by Java

Tags: here-olp

Is it any way to convert fast a HERE Geometry to a WKT representation, using Java? Any method available?

Thanx,
Sorin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are currently no library/methods to convert from 
 com.here.schema.geometry.v2.geometry.Geometry to WKT.